# How to get the first row of a dataframe with names when there is only one column?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

I'm facing an unexpected behavior with base R.

I want to retrieve the first row of a dataframe with its colnames as a vector, and this common method works perfectly for most cases.

```
df = data.frame(A=c(12,13), B=c(24,25))
unlist(df[1,]) #class=numeric
#    A  B
#   12 24
```

But when the dataframe is only composed of one column, the result is coerced to an unnamed vector:

```
df = data.frame(A=c(12,13))
unlist(df[1,]) #class=numeric too
# 12
```

How to keep the name is the second case?

Comment: `df[1,, drop = FALSE]`

Comment: @RonakShah Great, thanks! Could you please post it as an answer so I can accept it? This may be another question but this would not work with a matrix (as with the `t` function. Would you have any idea?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by this would not work with matrix ?

Comment: @RonakShah `df = t(data.frame(A=c(12,13)))` for instance

Comment: The above gives a matrix with rownames. So if you use `df[1, ,drop=FALSE]` it maintains the rownames.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When extracting a dataframe using `[` by default `drop` argument is `TRUE`.

From `?Extract`

> drop - If TRUE the result is coerced to the lowest possible dimension.

Also you can check the class for both the dataframe after extracting the row.

```
df1 = data.frame(A=c(12,13), B=c(24,25))
df2 = data.frame(A=c(12,13))

class(df1[1, ])
#[1] "data.frame"
class(df2[1, ])
#[1] "numeric"
```

As we can see `df2` is coerced to a vector. Using `drop = FALSE` will keep it as dataframe and not drop the dimensions.

```
df2[1,, drop = FALSE]
#   A
#1 12

class(df[1,, drop = FALSE])
#[1] "data.frame"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want a named vector, then a single column data frame can be tricky to extract. A potential workaround can be,

```
do.call(c, df)[1]
#A1 
#12
```

Where,

```
str(do.call(c, df)[1])
 Named num 12
 - attr(*, "names")= chr "A1"
```

Note that since it converts all the values to named vector, it adds a numeric suffix after the name so it does not have duplicated names

Answer (score 2):

#### It's R default behavior.

By default R will convert single column `data.frames` into `vectors` (with `drop = TRUE`). It's a good habit to use the option `drop = FALSE` when dealing with `data.frames`. This way you can be safe that data type will not change.

So, instead of:

```
df[1,]
```

Use:

```
df[1, , drop = FALSE]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

From `dplyr`

`?slice`

> Choose rows by their ordinal position

```
library(dplyr)
slice(df, 1L)

#   A
#1 12

str(slice(df, 1L))
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  1 variable:
#$ A: num 12
```

If you want it to be a named number, you can `unlist` it.

```
str(unlist(slice(df, 1L)))
#Named num 12
# - attr(*, "names")= chr "A"
```

You can as well transpose it keeping column names.

```
colnames(t(unlist(slice(df, 1L))))

#"A"
```

Comment: `dplyr` FTW! My question was base R so I cannot accept this answer, but this feels much cleaner

Comment: This is just an alternative and for base r @Ronak's solution can be tailored `t(unlist(df[1,, drop = FALSE]))` to produce the same result when transposed.